# Change slider color

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am using [material design 2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular2-material/slider) slider and I want to change the color to white.
I know the color binding attribute is not available yet, but in the meantime is there hack I can use to override the css somehow?